# Wordpress query with several meta values as condition

Tags: php, wordpress

First time using wordpress query so not sure how to handle this problem. I want to get post titles where meta_key is 'tag' and meta_values are 'A, B, C'. Something similar to IN() function of sql query. How should I do to achieve that?

This is my code so far but it is not working as it ignores condition.

```
 //$tags consists of my meta_value ( A, B, and C) 
    foreach ($tags as $input) {


    $data[] = array( 'meta_key' => 'tag', 'meta_value' => $input, 'orderby' => 'post_date' ); 


    }




        $query = new WP_Query( $data );
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Post with more information about the query you want to build. Don't worry about using WordPress, just use words or psuedo SQL if you know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Custom Field Parameters section on the [WordPress Codex for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

The problem is you are rebuilding your entire `$data` array on each loop. This passes invalid parameters to WP_Query. So I imagine your getting undefined results.

You simply want to set `meta_value` directly or specify a `meta_query` parameter similar to the `IN` clause you described.

Comment: Well, thx for the comment. I will like to set the meta_value directly but the amount of my data is dynamic so I can't do it that way. As for meta_query, I am not too sure how to do it. Can you kindly show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason, after a few tries, I managed to get it done using meta_query. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great. Glad the link helped. I would encourage you to either comment back with the solution or answer your own question for the next passer-by.

Comment: As you suggested, I have posted the solution I got. I should have read more clearly the documentary before posting. What a dumb ques I ask here. Nevertheless, thanks for your help despite being asked a stupid ques. LOL

Comment: No worries. You were figuring something out. That's the whole point of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
$args = array(

    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'tag',
        'value' => $tags,
        'compare' => 'IN'
        ) 
    ),

    'orderby' => 'post_date'
```

);